# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I am unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The only options from the boot CD are options 2 and 3, to erase all data or the partitions. Option 1 is grayed out, which is what I want to do and not selectable. I am running a dual boot with Windows Vista. My Ubuntu is on a USB portable HDD.

Comment: As Ubuntu 14.04.1 released a few days ago. Rather than upgrading from CD/DVD, You can wait a little more. Very soon LTS-LTS upgrade will be available to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS users. This will be 100% hassle free and can be easily done using Update Manager.

Comment: You can check the release note at : https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-July/000188.html